# SIP Redirect Server

Tags: sip, opensips

I'm trying to create a SIP redirect server for LCR routing purpose, I have a basic question here:
is opensips is the best solution, and is there other free easier solutions?

Any info on this will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly simple to do in [opensips](https://www.opensips.org/) with [sl_send_reply](https://www.opensips.org/Documentation/Tutorials-Redirect) or [freeswitch](https://freeswitch.com/) with [dialplan tools redirect](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+redirect).

If your clients all support SIP 302 redirect that's great. Otherwise you may need to proxy the audio for some legacy clients.

Comment: great, I need someone to guide me to achieve my goal, do you provide this service ? if yes please share your contact so we can cooperate